# Ria Service: Included Entities null when returning back to the service

Tags: silverlight, ria

I use the `Include` attribute on my properties, and they are transferred back properly to the client, but once I sent it back to the ria service for further processing the property are now null.

```
internal sealed class lSyncMetadata
{    
    private lSyncMetadata()
    {
    }

    public string ConflictMessage { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateInserted { get; set; }

    public Guid vValueId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public bool IsConflict { get; set; }

    public bool IsReadyToSync { get; set; }

    public Guid SyncSet { get; set; }
    [Include]
    public vValue vValue { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: Have you called Include on your object context?

Comment: No the lSync object is created on client side and so is vValue, when I pass the instance of lSync to my ria service to save the object, vValue is null.

Comment: Is vValue a new object? If not, RIA will only send the vValueId to the server since it do not need the whole object.

Comment: Yes Leo, vValue is a new object, sadly I need the whole object in the server :( Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIA Services Client does not serialize any property except value type and string, because usual navigation properties can lead to circular references and it will be impossible to determine what to send and what not to send. More over, in order to reduce network traffic and in order to maintain proper change tracking, ChangeSets are submitted by RIA Services but only for the entities it is tracking.

RIA Services are designed to replicate Entity Tracking on client side and you are expected to update, fetch navigation properties (related entities) on demand and you should let RIA Services manage what to send and what not to send.

However Include only works from Server to Client, it does not work from Client to Server, indeed if you make changes to navigation properties, RIA Services will determine and send ChangeSets correctly.

For anything apart from this, you will have to create a normal WCF Service or Web Service to make this work and access that from client.

Complex Types including only value types are supported, but they can not be of type Entity having Entity Key.

Comment: Isn't the the value type thing changed since Ria V1 SP1. Which supports Complex Object type serialization or am I misreading your answer?

Comment: Thanks, sadly what I did was just created a complex object and embed the properties of vValue on my lSync instead of lSync having an instance of vValue.